# xPages issue in Domino

Tags: xpages

I am editing and saving a xPages/custom control in Lotus Notes/Domino it works fine in web browser.
But then suddenly when refreshing the web browser I get the error as seen below.
After that I am stuck and the URL get some kind of locked with the error as seen below. The code seems to be corrupt and database can not be opened via web browser anymore.

**Error 403
HTTP Web Server: You are forbidden to perform this operation**

Comment: Seems to be signature problem of your design. Sign your database with identity having all required permissions.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but I have tried this but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Hi again, after adding my own name in the server document field "Sign agents or XPages to run on behalf of the invoker" it suddenly work again.